# How can create menu for telegram bot in bot father?

Tags: webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm new in telegram bot and see this bot:
[image]

that but when type `/start` show menu to me and with out type slash to command just fire the menu button,how can i create menu in telegram like that bot?

Comment: That's not something you can do in botfather, you need to do that in your bot's source code. And for us to help you with that, you will need to provide us with an example of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add the return ajax call a string like this:

```
'{ "keyboard": [["uno :+1:"],["uno \ud83d\udc4d", "due"],["uno", "due","tre"],["uno", "due","tre","quattro"]]}';
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: How we can return it?

Comment: bot.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id,  'Main Menu', {
                reply_markup: {
                    inline_keyboard: [code from sample below - sihould be an array of arrays]
                }
            })