# Telegram bot inline keyboard via Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm using the **node-telegram-bot-api** module,
How can I make my keyboard to inline Keyboard?
This is my code:

```js
bot.onText(/^\/start$/, function (msg) {
    const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: {
            resize_keyboard: true,
            one_time_keyboard: true,
            keyboard: [ ['Level 1'] ]
        }
    };

    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "I'm a test robot", opts);
});
```

Comment: what result would you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a question similar to this link: [How can create menu for telegram bot in bot father?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956166/how-can-create-menu-for-telegram-bot-in-bot-father/41967373#41967373)

in your case you could use:

```
keyboard: [["uno :+1:"],["uno \ud83d\udc4d", "due"],["uno", "due","tre"],["uno", "due","tre","quattro"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the solution would be:

```
const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: 
        [
            [{text: 'Level 1'}],
        ]
    })
  };
```

Comment: Does not work. Error: `Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: Text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard`

Answer (score 0):

You could use:
https://github.com/RealPeha/telegram-keyboard

The library if focused on Telegraf, but you could use without it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide an `InlineKeyboardButton` object instead of plain text in your `keyboard` array of arrays.

```
bot.onText(/^\/start$/, function (msg) {
    const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: {
            resize_keyboard: true,
            one_time_keyboard: true,
            keyboard: [
              [{text: 'Level 1'}],
            ],
        }
    };

    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "I'm a test robot", opts);
});
```